# RadTreeView not working

Tags: winforms, telerik, treeview

I'm having an issue with RadTreeView. It works fine when I use it in a normal dialog but when I have it inside a ToolWindow it does not highlight item when hover nor select. Here is my code to initiate a treeview in WinForms:

```
_foldersTree = new RadTreeView();
//_foldersTree.BeginInit();
_foldersWindow.Controls.Add(_foldersTree);
_foldersTree.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
//_foldersTree.ThemeName = "Telerik";
//_foldersTree.EndInit();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small piece of code I have tested with and the tree is fully clickable with hover and select effects:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    InitializeComponent();

```
RadDock dock = new RadDock();
dock.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(dock);

ToolWindow tw = new ToolWindow();
tw.Text = "Toolwindow";
dock.DockWindow(tw, DockPosition.Left);

RadTreeView tree = new RadTreeView();
tree.Nodes.Add("node1");
tree.Nodes.Add("node2");
tree.Nodes.Add("node3");

tw.Controls.Add(tree);
```

}

Here is the behavior I observe: [image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. That code is what I used but I does not render when I hover or select. I have to set Background color manually. That workaround's ugly

Comment: Couple things. Are you inheriting RadTreeView? If not, what is the version of the Telerik assemblies you use? Make sure ALL assemblies version is the same. Are you using the default theme.

Comment: I override the RadTreeView but don't have code inside my class. I use Telerik 2013 Q3

Comment: When you inherit controls, you need to override the ThemeClassName as described here: http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/tpf-inherit-themes-from-radcontrols-derivatives.html

Comment: That did the trick for me. I have another problem with RadListView that is similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25187177/radlistview-has-strange-behavior-when-creating-custom-cell-element-with-progress.

Comment: You need to do that will all inherited controls from Telerik UI for WinForms.

Comment: Telerik controls for WinForms seem to be poorly designed (both Architecture and the Look and feeling). It looks ugly in comparison to Office and Codejock.